Flatten JSON Array Using Jolt
I am trying to learn JOLT transformations, but not having a lot of luck with it. Just to try it out, I am grabbing some data from Disney, and trying to manipulate it. My input data is:
{
  "lands": [
    {
      "id": 56,
      "name": "Adventureland",
      "rides": [
        {
          "id": 1184,
          "name": "A Pirate's Adventure ~ Treasures of the Seven Seas",
          "is_open": false,
          "wait_time": 0,
          "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 134,
          "name": "Jungle Cruise",
          "is_open": true,
          "wait_time": 80,
          "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "name": "Fantasyland",
      "rides": [
        {
          "id": 133,
          "name": "\"it's a small world\"",
          "is_open": true,
          "wait_time": 55,
          "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
        },
        {
          "id": 132,
          "name": "Dumbo the Flying Elephant",
          "is_open": true,
          "wait_time": 60,
          "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

and i want my output to be:
[
  {
    "LandsID": 56,
    "LandsName": "Adventureland",
    "Ridesid": 1184,
    "Ridesname": "A Pirate's Adventure ~ Treasures of the Seven Seas",
    "is_open": false,
    "wait_time": 0,
    "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    "LandsID": 56,
    "LandsName": "Adventureland",
    "Ridesid": 134,
    "Ridename": "Jungle Cruise",
    "is_open": true,
    "wait_time": 80,
    "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    "LandsID": 57,
    "LandsName": "Fantasyland",
    "Ridesid": 133,
    "Ridesname": "\"it's a small world\"",
    "is_open": true,
    "wait_time": 55,
    "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
  },
  {
    "LandsID": 57,
    "LandsName": "Fantasyland",
    "Ridesid": 132,
    "Ridesname": "Dumbo the Flying Elephant",
    "is_open": true,
    "wait_time": 60,
    "last_updated": "2024-04-01T15:05:44.000Z"
  }
]

But I am not having any luck. Any assistance would be appreciated! Also, if here is a "JOLT For Dummies" or equivalent resource out there, I would love to see it. I am not finding a lot of learning material for it. Thanks!

Some sources to worth having a look at them ;1, 2, 3, 4.

... and the basic reference document : https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases

You should loop through the inner(rides) arrays while importing two outer values into respective objects such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "lands": {
        "*": { // represents the level of the indexes of the "lands" array
          "rides": {
            "*": { // represents the level of the indexes of the "rides" array
              "@2,id": "&3_&1.&4id", // match with the elements from 2 upper levels on LHS
              // determine the separated keys of the upcoming objects
              // by the indexes of the arrays through use of &3 and &1
              // &4 replicates the key "lands" by going 4 levels up to grab it              
              "@2,name": "&3_&1.&4name",
              "id|name": "&3_&1.&2&", // rename "id" and "name" with ridesid and ridesname
              // by going 2 level up the tree by &2
              "*": "&3_&1.&" // the rest of the attributes
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys and convert the JSON array of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Thanks so much! I am still trying to understand what you did; as JOLT remains a mysterious black box to me, but I will dig into it!
